# How to prove $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \sigma(n / d) = n$?

Tags: number-theory

How can I show that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$;$$\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d)\sigma(n/d) = n$$ 
Where $\sigma$ is the [divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) and $\mu$ is the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

I am confused because isn't $\sum_{d \mid n}\mu(d)= 1$ if $n=1$ and 0 otherwise?

Comment: What are you confused about?

Answer (score 4):

The functions you are finding the convolution of are **multiplicative**. So their convolution is.

Thus you need only verify the equality for prime powers, and the result will follow for all $n$.

If a number $k$ is divisible by a square greater than $1$, then $\mu(k)=0$. So for prime powers the sum is easy to compute.

**Remark:** If $m$ is the product of $d$ distinct primes, then $\mu(m)=(-1)^d$. If $m$ is divisible by a square $\gt 1$, then $\mu(m)=0$.  For details, google the Möbius function.

Comment: $$n=\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma(\gcd(k,n))e^{2\pi i k/n}$$

Comment: @AndreNicolas Could you please write how you verify for prime powers. I did understand why we use only the prime powers, but how do we get n?

Comment: Let $n=p^k$, Then the divisors $d$ of $n$ are $d=1,p,p^2,\dots,p_k$. When $d\ge p^2$, $\mu(d)=0$. So the only interesting terms correspond to $d=1$ and $d=p$. When $d=1$, $\mu(d)=1$ and $\sigma(n/d)=1+p+p^2+\cdots +p^k$. When $d=p$, we hane $\mu(d)=-1$, and $\sigma(n/d)=1+p+\cdots +p^{k-1}$. Subtract. We get almost total cancellation, the result is $p^k=n$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{d \mid n} d = \sigma(n)$$ and so by the [Möbius inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), we have that

$$\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \sigma\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = n$$