# Proving the following using Mobius Inversion.

Tags: number-theory

I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360882/how-to-prove-sum-dn-mud-sigman-d-n) question regarding Möbius Inversion. The question was "How can I show that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$;$$\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d)\sigma(n/d) = n$$ 
Where $\sigma$ is the divisor function and $\mu$ is the Möbius function." The answer was "$$\sum_{d \mid n} d = \sigma(n)$$ and so by the Möbius inversion formula, we have that

$$\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \sigma\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = n".$$

My question is, what if the arguments were swapped? That is, how would you prove that if $f(n)=\sum_{d|n}\sigma(d)\mu(n/d) $ then $f(n)=n$?

**Some properties of the "divisor function":**

$\displaystyle \sigma (n) = \sum_{d|n} d$.

$\displaystyle \sigma (p^e) = 1+p+p^2+...+p^e = \frac{p^{e+1}-1}{p-1}$.

$\sigma$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Just rewrite the first sum above with $d'=n/d$ and $d=n/d'$, and it follows from what you have, because with $d\mid n$ running through the divisors of $n$, so does $d'=n/d$.